# In concrete terms, what is a game/physics engine?

Tags: game-engine

I often heard about CryEngine, Unreal Engine, etc., but it is hard to imagine what it is about and why some are more powerful than others.

Can I say it is a high level library?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I say it is a high level library ?

I would say no, because game engines are typically more like operating systems than they are libraries.

Fabien Sanglard's code reviews of some famous older games are exceptional, and give some great insight into modern game engines. I especially recommend the Quake source code review; in many ways Carmack's Quake engine is the precursor to almost every current-gen 3D engine:

- http://fabiensanglard.net/quakeSource/index.php